# Keeping track of skipped numbers in Python

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to Python and I'm looking for a way for Python to keep track of skipped numbers in a sequence. For example, if I have a folder with pictures numbered 1-100, but 47, 58 and 98 are missing in the directory, how can I keep track of this?

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract your set with missing numbers from a complete set of all the numbers, e.g.:

```
>>> incomplete_set = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9 }
>>> complete_set = set(range(10))
>>> complete_set - incomplete_set
set([5, 7])
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But, lets say I didn't know which numbers are missing? Will it still work the same way?

Comment: Yes, you just have to construct the set of numbers you do know about and then create the complete set based on the max of those numbers and subtract - the result will be all the missing numbers.